# If Statements in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

so the problem is I have a search functionality everything works, except that when an item has not been found, you see it should display the text "champion has not been found" but it is not. I am hitting my head with this I would really appreciate the help. Where am I making a mistake?

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import data from './data.json'
import  './Champions.css'
import Skills from './Skills'
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';



const Champions = ({searchValue}) => {
  const [toggleShow, setToggleShow] = useState(false);
  const [currentSelectedChampion, setCurrentSelectedChampion] = useState({});


  const handleSelectChampion = (id) => {
    if (!toggleShow) setToggleShow(true);
    const currentChampion = data.filter((champ) => champ.id === id)[0];
    setCurrentSelectedChampion(currentChampion);

  };


 const filterChampions=(champion)=> {
    return champion.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  }



  return (
    <div className="champions">  
    {data.filter(filterChampions).map((champion) => {
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(champion.id))
       return(<div className='not__found'>
        <h1>No champion has been found</h1>
     </div>)
        return (
          
          <div key={champion.id} onClick={() => handleSelectChampion(champion.id) } >     
            <div className="champion">
              <img className="champion__Image" src={champion.image}></img>
              
              <h4 className="champion__Name">{champion.name}</h4>        
              {toggleShow && currentSelectedChampion.id === champion.id && (                
                <>
                  <Skills currentChampion={currentSelectedChampion} />
                    <CloseIcon onClick={() => setToggleShow(false)}/>              
                </>
              )}
             </div>
          </div>

          
        );
      })}
         
    </div>
  );
};

export default Champions
 json
[ {   
  "id":1,
 "name": "Attrox",
 },
 {"id":2,
 "name": "Ahri",
 }]
```

Comment: What's in `data.json`. Sample?

Comment: ```[
{    
"id":1,
"name": "Attrox",
},
{"id":2,
"name": "Ahri",
}] ```

Comment: I think checking for the id Inside the map function is the wrong idea. Pull the if out, and check if the result of your filter call has something in it, then map. Else display your error output. Data likely won't have the the value of champion.id as a property.

Comment: Please add relevant details, like that JSON response data to the question itself by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66536483/edit)

Comment: @codemonkey Not working my friend

Comment: Because based on your sample data, this make zero sense: `if(data.hasOwnProperty(champion.id))`

Comment: @codemonkey ```data.filter.length === 0``` length cant work, because champion is an object, is it?

Comment: The result of filter is an array.